# Java: Convert String to org.eclipse.uml2.uml.Type

Tags: java, uml, eclipse-emf-ecore

Is it possible to convert a String to a type, which is definied by org.eclipse.uml2.uml.Type? We need this information to generate a uml file with emf and ecore, but we only get the type information as a String.

Thank you!

Comment: What does your string look like? A fully qualified typename? For what---a particular UML model file?

Comment: For example: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, java.lang.String

Comment: Do you have a UML model at hand? Such a `Type` must refer to a model or profile defining it. You can't just start with your typename, you also need the class diagram to look in for it.

Comment: Yeah! We have a kdm model and want to generate a uml model out of this kdm model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote in your comments, your problems is NOT getting a UML type for a qualified method name-you apparently want to create the UML which corresponds to your KDM!

Either you turn you KDM into a UML model manually, drawing the class diagram in a suitable editor, or you do it programmatically. There, you'd start with a (empty) UML model, and add (create) all the (UML) classes to it that you need (e.g. through [`Package.createOwnedClass(name, isAbstract) : Class`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.uml2.doc/references/javadoc/org/eclipse/uml2/uml/Package.html#createOwnedClass%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29).

From looking at the class hierarchy, you can see that [a `Class` is also a `Type`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.uml2.doc%2Freferences%2Fjavadoc%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fuml2%2Fuml%2FClass.html). You know the root of your model (a package), you know where you put the classes (maybe in a subpackage), so you know where to look by name for a particular class using [`Package.getOwnedType(name) : Type`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.uml2.doc/references/javadoc/org/eclipse/uml2/uml/Package.html#getOwnedType%28java.lang.String%29).